# Make cells of different sizes conected without gaps

Tags: ios6, uicollectionview

I'm using a UICollectionView (and PSTCollectionView for legacy compatibility). What I want to achieve is to create a grid with elements of different heights. Right now they are aligned into rows like this:

[image]

You see black gaps and that rows are all aligned. Each new row of cells starts from the same Y pixel, i.e. all of them are placed into container, that equals to height of tallest cell.

Is there any standard way to remove those gaps? So that rows are rendered one below another with no gap?

Comment: Your drawings make no sense to me...

Comment: Hi David! I'm sorry, I can't post images because I'm novice at Stack. But I've inserted a link. Could you please look at it?

Comment: So that is how it currently looks. Can you post a mock up of how you wanted it to look? I'm not sure if you want to crop or completely lose the sense of rows.

Answer (score 0):

Provided your cells have all the same width, you can set the `CollectionViewFlowLayout`'s `scrollDirection` property to `UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal`. This will make the layout fill the content area column by column, without gaps.

If you want to get rid of the gaps **and** scroll vertically, you can't do that with `CollectionViewFlowLayout`. The way to go would be to subclass `CollectionViewLayout` and implement the layout yourself.

Comment: Chris, thank you! Subclassing was a good idea. I'm really new at StackOverflow, will it be helpful if I share the code here so anyone, looking for the same answer, will use it?

Comment: Note, you may be able to **simply use two columns** .. just have two collections, one for each column.